# Fix Pixel Shader "Stage did not run. No output"

Tags: directx11, fragment-shader

I'm trying to set up a minimal D3D11 renderer but fail to get the pixel shader stage to run. The available answers here or the ones I found through Google couldn't help me, unfortunately.

Using Visual Studio's Graphics Debugger I could verify that my vertices are set correctly and the vertex shader also runs as expected. The debug layer doesn't report any issues either. As a test I disabled depth testing, stencil testing and backface culling as shown below with no changes.

I made sure that the viewport is set correctly as well as this seems to be a common source of this problem.

At this moment I can't think of any other cause for this issue and would be happy about any advice of what else to look out for.

- Disable depth/stencil test:

  ```
  D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC dsstate_desc = {};
  dsstate_desc.DepthEnable             = false;
  dsstate_desc.StencilEnable           = false;
  dsstate_desc.DepthFunc               = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
  dsstate_desc.DepthWriteMask          = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
  dsstate_desc.BackFace.StencilFailOp  = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
  dsstate_desc.BackFace.StencilPassOp  = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
  dsstate_desc.BackFace.StencilFunc    = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
  dsstate_desc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
  dsstate_desc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
  dsstate_desc.FrontFace.StencilFunc   = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
  d3d11device->CreateDepthStencilState(&ds_state, &this->ds_state);
  d3d11context->OMSetDepthStencilState(this->ds_state, 0);
  ```
- Disable backface culling:

  ```
  D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rasterizer_desc = {};
  rasterizer_desc.AntialiasedLineEnable = false;
  rasterizer_desc.CullMode              = D3D11_CULL_NONE;
  rasterizer_desc.DepthBias             = 0;
  rasterizer_desc.DepthBiasClamp        = 0.0f;
  rasterizer_desc.DepthClipEnable       = false;
  rasterizer_desc.FillMode              = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
  rasterizer_desc.FrontCounterClockwise = true;
  rasterizer_desc.MultisampleEnable     = false;
  rasterizer_desc.ScissorEnable         = false;
  rasterizer_desc.SlopeScaledDepthBias  = 0.0f;
  d3d11device->CreateRasterizerState(&rasterizer_desc, &this->rasterizer_state);
  d3d11context->RSSetState(this->rasterizer_state);
  ```
- Pipeline view in debugger:

[image: Pipeline stages]

- Vertex shader transformation:

[image]

- Vertex shader:

  ```
  struct VertexIn
  {
      float3 position : POSITION;
      float3 normal   : NORMAL;
      float4 color    : COLOR;
  };

  struct VertexOut
  {
      float4 color    : COLOR;
      float4 position : SV_POSITION;
  };

  VertexOut main(VertexIn i)
  {
      VertexOut o;
      o.position = float4(i.position, 1.0f);
      o.color = i.color;
      return o;
  }
  ```
- Pixel shader:

  ```
  struct FragmentIn
  {
      float4 color    : COLOR;
      float4 pos      : SV_POSITION;
  };

  float4 main(FragmentIn i) : SV_TARGET
  {
      return float4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, for future readers: I Failed to set up a correct blend state. For some reason I forgot to set the write mask for the render target. Works perfectly after setting

```
blend_desc.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;
```